# Разделительный знак препинания

Tags: запятые, учебное-задание

Помогите, пожалуйста, с заданием. Укажите предложение с разделительным знаком препинания.

1) Дом, который стоял на берегу, принадлежал старому бакенщику.

2) Я хочу, чтоб к штыку приравняли перо

3) Когда в товарищах согласья нет, на лад их дело не пойдёт

4) Ямщик свистнул, и лошади поскакали.

Из разделительных знаков здесь только запятая. Предполагаю, что это или 3-й или 4-й вариант. Запятая разделяет два простых в составе сложного, но какой правильный ответ не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь ошибка в задании, правильно: Укажите **предложения** с разделительными знаками препинания.

1) Дом, который стоял на берегу, принадлежал старому бакенщику (СПП).

2) Я хочу, чтоб к штыку приравняли перо (СПП)

3) Когда в товарищах согласья нет, на лад их дело не пойдёт (СПП).

4) Ямщик свистнул, и лошади поскакали (ССП)

**Разделительные запятые в предложениях 2, 3, 4.** В предложении 1 выделительными являются две запятые.

**Пояснение**

**Разделительные** знаки **делят** предложение на смысловые части (или текст на предложения).

**Выделительные** знаки — это **парные знаки**, они характерны для **выделения** и обособления  смысловых частей **внутри предложения**. В сложноподчиненных предложениях они выделяют придаточное, находящееся внутри главного.

Comment: Получается, что если придаточное стоит после главного, то запятая разделительная, а если внутри главного, то запятые выделительные?

Comment: Ну да, а как иначе. Мы выделяем придаточное, которое находится внутри главного предложения. Если придаточное стоит перед главным или наоборот, то мы обозначаем границу между ними.

Comment: Спасибо! Опечатка в сборнике. Сразу за этим идет задание, в котором просят найти предложение с выделительными знаками препинания, и там также три правильных варианта. Думаю, вопросы перепутали.

Answer (score 1):

Верным ответом будет вариант 4.

`Ямщик свистнул` - первая основа.

`Лошади поскакали` - вторая

Остальные запятые ставятся для отделения различных оборотов, в которых нет собственной грамматической основы. Поэтому они не подходят

И, как небольшое замечание. В вашем вопросе после слова "уважаемые" не ставится запятая